# How can I choose the optimal clusters number in Elbon method?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I always have doubts about how can I choose the optimal cluster number using the Elbon method. In the following figure, what is the optimal number? I guess it´s five but I'm not sure.

[image]

For this case, I plot clusters for K=4,5 and 6

Four:
[image]

Five:

[image]

Six:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no definitive answer to this question. The optimal number of clusters is somehow subjective and depends on the method used for measuring similarities and the parameters used for partitioning.

The DBSCAN algo canestimate the number of clusters for you.  Check out this link.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py

Similarly, the Affinity Propagation algo can estimate the correct number of clusters that you should use.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_affinity_propagation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-affinity-propagation-py

Also, take a look at these links.

https://towardsdatascience.com/10-tips-for-choosing-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-277e93d72d92

https://towardsdatascience.com/cheat-sheet-to-implementing-7-methods-for-selecting-optimal-number-of-clusters-in-python-898241e1d6ad